# How do I deploy the Bipod?

Tags: arma-3

[image]

As you can see, this machine gun has a Bipod. 
I could not find any shortcut for this. Is there a way to use the Bipod of a machine gun?

Answer (score 3):

I can deploy by being prone and pressing <kbd>c</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

This bipod is purely aesthetic. You can't deploy it in the vanilla game.

But, you can use some mods to add some realism with it. 
First, VTS weapon resting mod http://www.armaholic.com/page.php?id=20817
Or, even if it does not replace original bipods in this current version, ASDG jointrail is a very good mod used by a lot a weapon addons. It brings realistic attachments as bipod to many weapons. http://www.armaholic.com/page.php?id=23242

The combination of that two mods can answer your expectations.

Comment: I believe now you can with Marksmen DLC purchased, however I don't know the key for that.

Comment: This answer was posted in 2014 and is no longer true. You can now use the bipods.